# A PyInstaller packaged wxPython simple Hello-World app crashes on macOS

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, wxwidgets, pyinstaller

**Running (windowed) wxPython Hello-World on macOS fails.**

- PyInstaller: both 3.2 and 3.3.dev0+8892e11
- Python: 2.7.12
- wxPython: 3.0.2.0
- osx-cocoa OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

The hello world example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Packaged using PyInstaller 3.2 with the following command:

```
pyinstaller -F --windowed hello-world.py
```

Error output in the terminal shows:

```
...
...
./src/common/stdpbase.cpp(62): assert "traits" failed in Get(): create wxApp before calling this
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any ideas or tips to solve this?